# Django : how to Identify who is saving the model from program?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-users

How do I check from the django code, which User is saving a model currently ?

I need to throw Validation Errors or assign some permissions to him from that.

Comment: [django-audit-log](https://github.com/Atomidata/django-audit-log/blob/master/audit_log/middleware.py) set current user via pre-save signal. Perhaps it is a solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you execute the `model.save()` from a view function, you can get the current user with `request.user`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

def myview(request):
    model = Model(...)
    model.save()
    permission = Permission.objects.get(codename="...")
    request.user.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

**EDIT: Access the request in a form**

The simplest way to get at the request from your form validation code is probably to set a attribute on the form instance:

```
def myview(request):
    ...
    form = SomeForm(...)
    form.request = request
```

Inside your form validation logic you can now use `self.request` to access the user:

```
class SomeForm(...):
    def clean_somefield(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data["somefield"]
        if self.request.user....:
             raise ValidationError()
```

Comment: Thanks!  But how do I throw a ValidationError here ? It wont give me an error in the form itself would it ?
It would probably cause 500 internal server page to be echoed. I want it to be at the form level. Is there anyway I can get the user at the form level? .`model_save` is not a choice for me